# Issue With httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: centos, networking, apache-httpd

I'm Having Issue starting Httpd Service since it's given the following Error:

**httpd[5328]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::f03c:91ff:fed5:adf4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message**

My Hostname is AmericaN

So what to do in that case?

The output of /etc/hosts is :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: It isn't an error, simply a notice.  As the message says you'd need to set ServerName in the main config (not in a vhost) and it should be a FQDN that can be looked up via DNS or /etc/hosts

Comment: @ivanivan that's the output of my /etc/hosts  

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


so what shall i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first i were running httpd by " yum install httpd " and then starting it By " service httpd start "

but once i changed the hostname to be different than default and set it to AmericaN and configured the DNS to 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 then i lost access on apache and were not able to access my public ip using browser.

so after doing some research i found a solution for my issue by allowing firewalld to recognize my traffic on port 80/443 http/https using the following command :

sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent

Comment: forgot to mention that in case if anyone wanna resolve the error MSG by httpd/apache, then you need to go to nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and uncomment ServerName and make it to be ServerName localhost

Comment: Note: If you are not sure of the location of your httpd.conf the use `httpd -V` and look for something like:  -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"

Answer (score 3):

The warning message is telling you exactly what you need to do to resolve it:  Add a `ServerName` directive in your Apache configuration for at least one of each `VirtualHost` attached to each interface for which there is a `Listen` directive.

Comment: I'm Not installed Apache, I'm using httpd only.

Comment: `httpd` _is_ Apache in nearly all cases, and the message you cite is very typical of Apache.

Comment: so could you please explain for me what shall i do exactly if you don't mind !

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put **ServerName localhost** inside as well as outside your VirtualHost tags.